# How to position a UITableView correctly at a fixed point from the top of the view?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to position a `UITableView` 200 points from the top of the view. I'm able to do that with the following code. The problem I have is that half of the last row doesn't scroll and is obscured/hidden.

How can I change this line    `self.mainTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,200,320,600);` so that the table ends at the bottom of the view correctly and is sized so that all rows scroll fully within the view.

```
self.mainTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.mainTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,200,320,600);
self.mainTableView.autoresizingMask = ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth );
self.mainTableView.dataSource = self;
self.mainTableView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.mainTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,200,320,self.view.frame.size.height-200);
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this to make table touch the end of the screen :

```
self.mainTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 600, 320, 600);
```

Comment: Read question carefully, his problem is regarding scrolling not position of tableview.

Comment: @Girish This is from the question itself "How can I change this line self.mainTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,200,320,600); so that  the TABLE ENDS at the BOTTOM of the VIEW".

Comment: His problem is scrolling the table entirely.

Comment: He solved his problem just by changing the position. And that is what I suggested.

Comment: He solved his problem by setting the frame of table not setting the position of table. As per your solution, height of self.view is 480 - 600 = -120 & he wants to set the origin of y from 200.