# iOS/Xcode/storyboard: How to adjust size of UITableView in UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I created a UIViewController and then placed a UITableView in it. Initially it let me resize the UITableView, but now it no longer lets me do this. The UITableView dimensions are not enabled (they show 600 x 600) and the handles do not appear on the edges of the UITableView to drag in storyboard.

Can anyone suggest a fix to this. I have wasted 2 days on this problem.

I already have deleted the screens and recreated them multiple times and the same problem continues to happen.

The reason I want to make the UITableView take up less than the whole screen is to have some buttons on the screen as well.

Answer (score 3):

First of all please give some visuals for your question .
You can try this .

Write following code it might be helpful to

```
                 you.self.mainTableView.frame =           CGRectMake(0,200,320,self.view.frame.size.height-200);

     //     You can set your x,y.hight,width .
```

Or

Check your autoresizing masks. Those can mess up view structures easily.

Or

Also refer this page .
[How to position a UITableView correctly at a fixed point from the top of the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165468/how-to-position-a-uitableview-correctly-at-a-fixed-point-from-the-top-of-the-vie)